# Swift iOS SKActions not working for sprites brought in from SKS file

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, xcode9, skaction

I have a spriteKit project that brings sprites to the scene by loading them from an sks file. I know that they are loading correctly because I can perform other functions on them. In the simulator they even run SKActions, but on an actual device (iPad pro gen 2) they do not run those actions. I made the following test program that illustrates the problem.

The question specifically is why don't sprites that have been loaded from an SKS file run SKActions on a real device?

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {


private var fileDropSite: SKSpriteNode!

var lessonNode: SKSpriteNode?
var lessonButton: SKSpriteNode?


override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    fileDropSite = childNode(withName: "fileDropSite") as! SKSpriteNode

}

func bringSKSTOLoad() {
    fileDropSite.removeAllChildren()
    let lessonToLoad = SKSpriteNode(fileNamed: "practiceLesson")?.childNode(withName: "unitNode")
    lessonToLoad?.move(toParent: fileDropSite)

    lessonNode = fileDropSite.childNode(withName: "//lessonNode") as? SKSpriteNode
    lessonButton = fileDropSite.childNode(withName: "//lessonButton") as? SKSpriteNode
    print("lessonLoaded")
}


override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
        let touchedNode = atPoint(touchLocation)
        if let nodesName = touchedNode.name {
            if nodesName == "fileDropSite" {
                print("fileDropSite TOuched")
                bringSKSTOLoad()
            }
            if nodesName == "lessonButton" {
                print("lessonButton TOuched")
                lessonNode?.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.moveBy(x: -100, y: 0, duration: 0.5), SKAction.moveBy(x: 100, y: 0, duration: 0.5)])))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to clarify: fileDropSite is a child sprite in the gamescene, lessonNode and lessonButton are sprites in the file named practiceLesson and are children of the sprite named unitNode. The following code initializes these as variables and upon touching the fileDropSite sprite, it then loads the sprites in the file to the scene via the fileDropSite(child of the scene), and initializes them. There is a touch function that causes the lessonNode and its child to shake back and forth on the simulator but not on a rea device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try...

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    fileDropSite = childNode(withName: "fileDropSite") as! SKSpriteNode
    self.isPaused = false
}
```

as of iOS11 Apple has made the default state for scenes and SKSpriteNodes to be paused. Generally running `self.isPaused = false` on the scene works for me.

and if need be try...

```
func bringSKSTOLoad() {
    fileDropSite.removeAllChildren()
    let lessonToLoad = SKSpriteNode(fileNamed: "practiceLesson")?.childNode(withName: "unitNode")
    lessonToLoad?.move(toParent: fileDropSite)

    lessonNode = fileDropSite.childNode(withName: "//lessonNode") as? SKSpriteNode
    lessonButton = fileDropSite.childNode(withName: "//lessonButton") as? SKSpriteNode
    print("lessonLoaded")
    lessonToLoad.isPaused = false
    lessonNode.isPaused = false
    lessonButton.isPaused = false
}
```

Comment: My first thought exactly, I had already tried to set the fileDropSite.isPaused to false but it hadn't occurred to me to iterate through everything else. But you were right. It turns out in this case that since it was the lessonNode that I was going to perform the action on that it needs to be unPaused specifically. I guess its not enough to just un-pause the parent that it comes from. Still, I cant believe I spent most of the day brooding over this! Thanks so much.

Comment: your welcome, glad it helped. please mark this a correct then so that others can benefit from this question.

Comment: Done! Thanks again.